# I convert Int to Float but the Id-Type doesn't change

Tags: c++, type-conversion, static-cast

I convert int to float and input 1.23 to 'a' but output is 1
what is wrong?

```
int a = 123;
static_cast<float>(a);
cout << typeid(a).name(); //int

cin >> a; //1.23
cout << a;  //1


return 0;
```

Comment: Your code takes the value of a, converts the value of a to float without affecting a, and throws the result away. Which is completely pointless and a is unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to asign the return value to a variable of the preferred type:

```c
float result = static_cast<float>(your_var);
```